# How to add custom attribute filter to LoadByEmail function in magento

Tags: customer

I have added custom attribute is_website user to customer.What i want is when the customer logins it should check if is_websiteuser attribute=1 if it is 1 then only allow the user to login else stay on same page..
Until now i found that LoadByEmail consist of the query,but it is not workin if we write

```
$select  = $adapter->select()
        ->from($this->getEntityTable(), array($this->getEntityIdField()))
        ->where('email = :customer_email')
        ->where('is_webshopuser',1);//my code to add filter
```

Can you plz tell how this should be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try the following?

```
$select = $this->_getReadAdapter()->select()
            ->from($this->getEntityTable(), array($this->getEntityIdField()))
            ->joinNatural(array('cev' => $this->getTable('customer_entity_int')))
            ->joinNatural(array('ea' => $this->getTable('eav/attribute')))
            ->where('ea.attribute_code=\'is_webshopuser\' AND cev.value=?',$value);
```

Comment: Yes i tried it ,but it is not working :(

Comment: But wait, where is stored your attribute? the Attribute `email` is a static attribute for the customer entity. I suppose that you is_webshopuser is located into the eav_attribute table. So you have to provide the table which below to is_webshopuser eav attribute. In your case it may be some like `customer_entity_int`. Check my answer again I updated it

Comment: my attribute is present in eav_attribute.but still your code is not working,if i use this code it does not allow any user to login even if his is_webshopuser attribute=1..